# ACPI error while installing Ubuntu 16.04 on dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, acpi

I have an Asus fx553vd laptop (Intel Core i7 7700hq, Nvidia GTX 1050). Some weeks ago I sent it to the Asus Italian center to be repaired due to a stupid hardware problem and at that moment there were these 2 OSs installed:

1. Windows 10 in an SSD
2. Ubuntu 16.04 in an internal HDD

During the repair they formatted the PC and reinstalled Windows 10. I don't know what they did with Ubuntu, but it's gone and the internal hard drive is completely clean.

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu, always in dual boot with Windows. I created a live USB with Rufus with the Ubuntu .iso file. I switched on the PC and in the grub menu I chose the *Install Ubuntu* option.

The problem occurred here: a black screen appeared saying that there is an ACPI Error. The error says:

```
[0.028044] ACPI Error: [PRTO] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS
```

and other lines that explain the error.

[image]

After this error screen, the normal Ubuntu boot screen appears (the Ubuntu written above the five dots), but after a while it freezes, forcing me to manually switch off the PC. The BIOS is updated. I think that during the repair, the Asus technicians deleted Ubuntu in some wrong way, leaving something in the hard drive that's now compromising  reinstallation.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/745946/ubuntu-missing-from-hp-boot-menu

Comment: Rather than jump to conclusions I would begin by https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: I already tryed using Boot Repair from live USB doing 'Recommended Repair' but it changed nothing. My case is different from the other that you said because I don't have ubuntu installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved. I recommend you don't use UNetbootin to create the bootable USB; instead use Rufus if you are in Windows or use the command line if you are in Linux (`dd` command). The main problem was with the graphics drivers and these are the steps I followed to solve this issue:

1. Once you have launched the bootable USB and you see the GRUB menu, move the selector to **Try Ubuntu** or **Boot from live disk**, whichever option comes.
2. Press <kbd>E</kbd> in order to edit the install command you are about to run. Go to the line that starts with word `linux` (the one with the words `quiet splash`), go to the end of this line and after the --- put the following words: `nouveau.setmode=0`.
3. Press <kbd>f10</kbd> to boot the system
4. You can now run the installer
5. After reboot, repeat steps 2 and 3
6. Once you have booted go to terminal and type

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
   ```

   (384 is the latest and more stable driver version at the moment, replace this number with the last driver version you find on nvidia site in the future).
7. Now from menu go to **Additional Drivers**, go to proprietary drivers tab, select nvidia drivers and reboot

Last thing: if you experience screen tearing during Ubuntu use I suggest you to read the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941077/screen-tearing-on-nvidia-gtx960m).