# ACPI error after 16.04.3 install

Tags: 16.04, ssd, acpi, nouveau

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 (latest downloadable LTS) on my Acer V17 Nitro. It has a 256 Gb SSD, where I want the Ubuntu and the swap to live and a 1Tb HDD, where I will have long-term storage and probably a Windows partition for my wife to use from time to time (she doesn't like Ubuntu no matter what I do).

So I cleared out the SSD and am trying to install Ubuntu from the bootable drive I created from another Ubuntu 16.04 machine.

But no matter what combination of parameters I try (installing updates or not, installing 3rd-party software or not), when it comes to rebooting after the install it gives me this (and does not reboot):

[image: ACPI error]

I have tried what was proposed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948386/acpi-error-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-on-dual-boot-with-windows-10) and that way it does reboot, but sais can't find a bootable medium.

I have also tried booting from the USB drive with `nomodeset` instead of `quiet splash` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) but then it does not load and the screen just goes black.

**UPDATE**

Decided to take a different route and install Windows first and then put Ubuntu next to it.

I divided the SSD partition into 3 parts - swap, 140Gb for Ubuntu and 80Gb for Windows (using Windows 10 Home).

I installed Windows on its partition and it happily took its place and is running smoothly.

I then tried to install Ubuntu with `nouveau.setmode=0` as discribed in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948386/acpi-error-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-on-dual-boot-with-windows-10). It did install and went on reboot fine, but I am not able to boot Ubuntu, it boots directly to Windows.

And yes, I have tried Boot-Repair and moved the Windows Boot Manager to the bottom of the BIOS Boot sequence. Still it's not working.

Comment: The ACPI error can be ignored, for the moment, it doesn't prevent booting. The error thta comes *after* is what's preventing the correct boot and is about graphics so, you need `nomodeset` until you install the Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @MichaelBay, It can't be ignored, because the computer just doesn't turn off to reboot. And if I try hard reset, it shows 'No bootable device' unless I remove and replug the usb.

Comment: And what is nomodeset? And how do I ensure it when booting?

Comment: The Acer V17 Nitro has a very powerful and very new Nvidia GTX1060. Ubuntu provides an open-source driver for Nvidia Graphics but it doesn't support yours correctly yet. Nomodeset forces a generic compatible video mode albeit only useful to navigate you way to the drivers installation at the Additional Drivers tool. Can be installed with commands as well . Reboot.

Comment: It has 2 video cards - the NVidia and the Inter Graphics... 
Can you post a solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71571/discussion-between-almaron-and-michaelbay).

Comment: It's not an ACPI problem, it's a nouveau driver problem. Best solution is to use either Intel Integrated Graphics instead of nVidia GPU **-OR-** switch from nouveau driver to nVidia driver.

Comment: Great. can you tell me how to do it?