# How can I install Ubuntu on Acer Nitro 5?

Tags: boot, nvidia, system-installation, acer, 18.10

I have a new Acer Nitro 5 and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.10 on it. I disabled secure boot, tried `nomodeset` and it still didn't work. I got it to install adding `acpi=0`, but then it didn't recognize my wi-fi adapter... The laptop has a nvidia graphics card, and I heard it might be the issue with it, but I couldn't install it even with `nomodeset` active. The main issue seems to be that the mouse freezes completely. I have the same problems on 18.04.

I can access the terminal on the new install, but nothing else. I don't know what to do to solve it, I'm fairly new to Linux and I can't find this exact problem (or the solutions don't work). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try 18.04 LTS before trying 18.10 (non-LTS)

LTS means Long Term Support and can be considered to be more stable.
Especially if your problem could be hardware drivers. I'm curious how a LTS install would process.

Comment: I tried with 18.04 and had the same problem. I've been looking around some more and it seems to be an acer problem with acpi...

Comment: @CarmenZalvide possible solution? [1]https://askubuntu.com/a/989156/901991